# excel vba cycle through rows and output to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a DATA sheet which contains data rows as follows:
[image]

And I have a sheet named ROWBUILDER that has formulas and produces results like this:

[image]

I would like to write a VBA code that will cycle through every row in the ROWBUILDER sheet and output data to a new worksheet.
**NOTE:** The ROWBUILDER sheet must remain as is. Only the resulting data must be copied to the OUTPUT sheet.

I have no idea how to do it and from where to start. Will appreciate any help, examples or links.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? You could use VBA to fill down the formulas in `ROWBUILDER!A2:B2`; or you could do the same operations in VBA and just write the results to the worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This moves all the data to one output sheet.

```
Sub MoveROWBUILDER()
    Sheets("ROWBUILDER").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
    Sheets("Output").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

If you are looking for one sheet per row, try this. You may run into a limit depending on memory and the amount of data.

```
Sub DataToSheets()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rowCount As Integer, colCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim data() As Variant
    
    Sheets("ROWBUILDER").Select
    rowCount = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    colCount = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
    data() = Sheets("ROWBUILDER").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value2
    For i = 2 To rowCount
        Set sh = Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
        sh.Name = "Data" & (i - 1)
        For j = 1 To colCount
            sh.Cells(1, j) = data(1, j)
            sh.Cells(2, j) = data(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! No, I don't need 1 sheet per row. I just need every row from DATA worksheet to be placed inside ROWBUILDER. Once ROWBUILDER calculates the formula, then the row will be pasted to the first empty row in an OUPUT sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you can estimate the maximum number of rows in your data sheet then - instead of cycling through every row - you can use

```
rowbuilder.Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Copy
newworksheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Comment: DATA sheet is updated every time, sometimes I have 50 rows but sometimes 500.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop like this:

```
    numberRows = Range("A2").End(xlToDown).Row
    Sheets.Add.Name = "OUTPUT"
        For i = 2 To numberRows
            Sheets("OUTPUT").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("DATA").Cells(i, 1).Value
            Sheets("OUTPUT").Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("DATA").Cells(i, 8).Value & " " & Sheets("DATA").Cells(i, 7).Value & " " & Sheets("DATA").Cells(i, 6).Value & " " & Sheets("DATA").Cells(i, 5).Value
        Next i
```

Comment: I have tried it. It is looping but returning result also to ROWBUILDER sheet. I need result only in OUTPUT sheet.

Comment: Just add sheet with name OUTPUT and replace ROWBUILDER.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try this again now that I have a better idea of what you need.

You can process all of the rows at once using dynamics arrays in ROWBUILDER. Set C1 in ROWBUILDER to

```
=COUNTA(DATA!A:A) - 1
```

Then set A2 to

```
=OFFSET(DATA!A2,0,0,C1,1) & " " & OFFSET(DATA!B2,0,0,C1,1)
```

This will spill all of the full names to column A.  You can then set B2 to

```
=OFFSET(DATA!H2,0,0,C1,1) & " " & OFFSET(DATA!G2,0,0,C1,1) & " " & OFFSET(DATA!F2,0,0,C1,1) & OFFSET(DATA!E2,0,0,C1,1)
```

This will spill the Full Address to Column B.  IF you still need to copy it to OUTPUT, then this code should do the job.

```
Range("A2#").Copy
offsetrows = Sheets("OUTPUT").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
Sheets("OUTPUT").Select
Range("A1").Offset(offsetrows, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thank you! Excellent! First 2 codes work as I wanted! But Range("A2#").Copy returns an error: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Comment: I have remove # from Range("A2#").Copy and get only A2 filled with the correct value. Other column and rows are not filled.

Comment: Weird A2# should work with dynamic arrays.  It worked on mine.  As an alternative you can try Sheets("ROWBUILDER").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.offset(1,0).Copy.

Comment: This one Sheets("ROWBUILDER").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.offset(1,0).Copy. copies actually, but doesn't loop to insert all data into OUTPUT. Only the first row

Comment: If you have an older version of Excel, this may not work.  The modifications that I suggested to C1, A2 and B2 should list all of the rows from data in the format you are looking for.  If that isn't happening, then the macro code won't work.